# How to insert data from the included file and create HTML-elements automatically?

Tags: php

I want to insert data from included file and create HTML-elements automatically.

In **data.php** I have:

```
$vps_de_dc1_s1 = array(
"name"=>"Germany, DC1, First",
"price"=>"10€",
);

$vps_de_dc1_s2 = array(
"name"=>"Germany, DC1, Second",
"price"=>"10€",
);
```

$vps_de_dc2_s1 ..., $vps_de_dc2_s2 ..., $vps_cz_dc1_s1 ..., $vps_cz_dc12_s1 ..., etc.

And in **page.php** there should be:

```
include('data.php');

<tr class="vps_de_dc1">
    <td class="column-left">
        name
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        $vps_de_dc1_s1["name"]
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        $vps_de_dc1_s2["name"]
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        $vps_de_dc1_s3["name"]
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="vps_de_dc2">
    <td class="column-left">
        name
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        $vps_de_dc2_s1["name"]
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        $vps_de_dc2_s2["name"]
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        $vps_de_dc2_s3["name"]
    </td>
</tr>

...
```

I want to know, is it possible to automate somehow creation of table elements here?

---

Update: In fact, for `echo` I have to manually create all table instances. But I want to find a way to create all these `<tr class="vps_*_dc*">...</tr>` automatically for every `$vps_*` from data.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start with data.php. At the bottom, add a master array of all your arrays:

```
$masterArray = array(
    'vps_de' => array ('dc' => 2, 's' => 4), // The key is the root name.
    'vps_cz' => array ('dc' => 2, 's' => 4), // The value is information about how many dc and s exist per location.
    // This example means that this has 2 dc and 4 s for a total of 8 possible arrays that you've defined.
    ...
);
```

In page.php:

```
foreach ($masterArray as $varName => $infoArray) // Iterating through the master list.
{
    for ($dc = 1; $dc <= $infoArray['dc']; $dc++) // Iterating through however many numbers up to the dc limit.
    {
        $className = $varName . '_dc' . $dc; // Creating the class name, which is the location key root concatenated with the dc number.
        echo '<tr class="' . $className . '">'; // Echo the table row.
        for ($s = 1; $s <= $infoArray['s']; $s++) // Iterating through however many numbers up to the s limit.
        {
            $arrayName = $className . '_s' . $s; // Creating the name of the variable, reference to the array.
            if (isset($$arrayName)) // Checking to see if the variable by the name we just created exists.
            {
                $tmpArray = $$arrayName; // Using a variable variable to reference the array using its name.
                echo '<td class="column-left">';
                echo $tmpArray['name']; // I think you can use $$arrayName['name'] here, but it's been loaded to $tmpArray just to be safe.
                echo '</td>';
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Edit: After reading through your question some more, it appears that your requirements are more complex than I first thought.

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Good luck!

Comment: However, your code is very a good point to start for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include('data.php');

echo "
<tr class=\"vps_de_dc1\">
    <td class=\"column-left\">
       name
    </td>
    <td class=\"column-right\">".
       $vps_de_dc1_s1["name"].
    "</td>
    <td class="column-right">".
       $vps_de_dc1_s2["name"].
    "</td>
    <td class=\"column-right\">".
       $vps_de_dc1_s3["name"].
    "</td>
</tr>

<tr class=\"vps_de_dc2\">
    <td class="column-left">
       name
    </td>
    <td class=\"column-right\">".
       $vps_de_dc2_s1["name"].
    "</td>
    <td class=\"column-right\">".
       $vps_de_dc2_s2["name"].
    "</td>
    <td class=\"column-right\">".
       $vps_de_dc2_s3["name"].
    " </td>
</tr>"


?>
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, for `echo` I have to manually create all table instances. But I want to find a way to create all these `<tr class="vps_*_dc*">...</tr>` automatically for every `$vps_*` from data.php.